# MATLAB image summation confusion

Tags: matlab

I am trying to sum over my image (it is a 128x128 Uint8) in MATLAB (just a simple for loop), however, my sum will only go up to a value of 255. Afterwords it just keeps displaying 255 over and over again.

Does this mean that my variable has been assigned a Uint8 or something? If so how do I change this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, presumably your data is of type Uint8. But you don't have to loop to sum, just use the `sum` function. Assuming your data is in `x`:

```
total = sum(double(x(:)))
```

`sum` will operate over a single dimension, so if you just passed it `double(x)` directly, it would return a `1x128` matrix; here we have passed it all the data reshaped to a single-dimension vector (using `(:)`), which has been converted to double using the `double` function.

Note that the type of your variable will be displayed along with its name and size in the Workspace window.

Comment: Awesome, ah I see! Thanks, sorry for the rather silly question!

Comment: `sum` will actually convert any integer type to double by default before performing the summation. The explicit conversion is therefore not actually needed, but it doesn't hurt and does make it clear that you know that a conversion will need to happen.